# Geometric version of Hahn-Banach theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove the following geometric version of Hahn-Banach theorem:

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty open disjoint convex subsets of a normed linear space $E$. Then there exist a nonzero $f \in E^*$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \subset \{x \in E : f(x) > \alpha\}$ and $B \subset \{x \in E : f(x) < \alpha\}$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: A general hint.   To separate $A$ from $B$, we can separate $A - B$ from $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete proof (with multiple lemmas) is given in

*Haïm Brezis*, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, p. 4-8.

Comment: What happens when the sets are closed, or empty, or non-convex?